# Spritekit- how to NOT stop audio from background music/podcast app

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm working on a game that has some simple sound effects, but would like it to not interrupt my music player which is on in the background (which happens as soon as I load sounds). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [System Sound Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/), I don't believe there's anyway to do it if you just want to use SpriteKit actions.